# ng options select angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I try to load options with an arrangement that has the format I leave you, the first option is blank and the following are the values of my arrangement. That's a problem for me when I try to select one other option I can not get the value.

```
<select ng-model='form.type' 
    ng-options="item.name for item in organizations" 
    ng-change="update({{form.type.id}})">
</select>
```

Format :

```
{"status":0,"Area":[{"id":"1","name":"Marketing","private":null},{"id":"2","name":"Ventas","private":null},{"id":"5","name":"Soporte","private":null}],"Count":3}
```

Controller :

```
$scope.organizations = data.Area;
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please rephrase, and if you can create a fiddle demonstrating your problem. Also, the `update` function does nothing.

Comment: What exactly is in `form.type`? is it the string from `name` or an instance from the `Area` area? What is the HTML being generated now? What should the HTML you want look like?

Comment: Oh excuse me, I did not realize that bad copy my example, I will edit and put my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening in your case is that your `ng-model` variable, which is `form.type`, does not contain a value of your options in the select dropdown list. That's why you see an empty row. If you want it to be, for instance, the first one, you can do this (I changed to `selected` variable, but it doesn't matter at all):

```
$scope.organizations = [{"id":"1","name":"Marketing","private":null},{"id":"2","name":"Ventas","private":null},{"id":"5","name":"Soporte","private":null}];

$scope.selected = $scope.organizations[0].id;
```

Now, the `selected` variable has the `id` of your option. But that's not all. You also need to modify your HTML a bit, to have the `ng-options` have the `id` as your value. It can be anything you want in the object, not necessarily the `id`, but that's why I assumed you needed, you can change it:

```
<select ng-model='selected' ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in organizations" ng-change="update({{selected}})">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13586/)

Comment: Thank you friend, it worked perfect for me !, really do not quite understand what I was trying to do the same hahaha, but thanks to your help clarify me and I understood how it worked.